# rlang double curly braces within lm() formula

Tags: r, rlang

Is it possible to use the rlang tidy evaluation operator `{{` within an lm formula?

I know that you can use the double curly braces to define a general function such as this:

```
my_scatter <- function(df, xvar, yvar) {
     ggplot(df) +
          geom_point(aes(x = {{xvar}}, y = {{yvar}}))
}

my_scatter(mpg, cty, hwy)
```

But I was wondering whether there was a way to make a similar call within formulas such as inside lm():

```
my_lm <- function(df, yvar, xvar) {
     lm({{yvar}} ~ {{xvar}} , data = df)
}

my_lm(mpg, cty, hwy)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of nuances. First, `{{` is generally only supported in functions powered by tidyverse. [The upcoming `rlang::inject()` function](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/inject.html) will allow you to extend that support to arbitrary functions.

Second, `{{` is shorthand for `!!enquo()`, which captures the expression provided to the function AND the environment where that expression should be evaluated. Since the environment is already provided by the data frame `df`, the better verb to use here is `ensym()`, which captures the symbol only.

The following works with rlang 0.4.10:

```
my_lm <- function(df, yvar, xvar) {
    ysym <- rlang::ensym(yvar)
    xsym <- rlang::ensym(xvar)
    rlang::inject( lm(!!ysym ~ !!xsym, data=df) )
}

my_lm(mpg, cty, hwy)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lm` expects a formula object which you can construct using `reformulate`/`as.formula`.

```
my_lm <- function(df, yvar, xvar) {
  lm(reformulate(xvar, yvar), data = df)
}

my_lm(mpg, 'cty', 'hwy')
```